# Excel VBA - search columns by header and paste into new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste, paste

I am new to VBA...trying to search specific columns by name and paste them into a new sheet.

What I have so far seems clunky and does not copy or paste the desired column but what I currently have on my clipboard!

Ideally I would be able to search 3 different columns and paste them on to the new sheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Dim CheckText As String
Dim CheckRow As Long
Dim FindText As Range
Dim CopyColumn As String
CheckText = “Bsp” 'Bsp is an example header
CheckRow = 1 'Row with desired header
Dim oldsheet As Worksheet

Set oldsheet = ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Pivot"
oldsheet.Activate
ActiveSheet.Select
'trying here to create a new sheet, name it and go back to the first sheet
Set FindText = Rows(CheckRow).Find(CheckText)
If FindText Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Bsp not found"
End If

CopyColumn = Cells(CheckRow, FindText.Column).Column
Columns(CopyColumn).Select.Copy

Sheets("Pivot").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a generic example that you can adjust to fit your needs. The code will look for column header named `Some String`. **IF** this column is found, we next determine the last row, copy the column (down to last row), and then paste the column in cell `A1` on `Pivot` sheet.

1. Use the range variable `Found` to store your column header properties (namely location)
2. Check if the header is actually found! `If Not Found is Nothing` (Translation: Found)
3. Use `Found.Column` to reference the column index which fits into the `Cells` property nicely since the syntax is `Cells(Row Index, Column Index)`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<== Sheet that has raw data
Dim LRow As Long, Found As Range

Set Found = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find("Some String") '<== Header name to search for

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    LRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, Found.Column), ws.Cells(LRow, Found.Column)).Copy
    Sheets("Pivot").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '<== Sheet to paste data
End If

End Sub
```

You are going to want to amend some of the options on the `Range.Find` method. Details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. Your code worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code in an attempted to search for another header and copy and paste it
Option Explicit

```
Sub Test()


Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Pivot"
ws.Activate
ActiveSheet.Select

Dim LRow As Long, Found As Range

Set Found = ws.Range("A1:EM1").Find("Bsp") '<== Header name to search for


If Not Found Is Nothing Then
LRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, Found.Column), ws.Cells(LRow, Found.Column)).Copy
Sheets("Pivot").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '<== Sheet to paste data
End If

ws.Activate
ActiveSheet.Select

Set Found = ws.Range("A1:EM1").Find("Sog")

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
LRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, Found.Column), ws.Cells(LRow, Found.Column)).Copy
Sheets("Pivot").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If

End Sub
```